# How to nest two keys in iOS to make API call

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby-on-rails, json, api

This is how I post to an API:

`curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://sub.domain.com/api/v1/sections.json -d "{\"section\":{\"properties\":{\"email\":\"example@email.com\",\"department\":\"dpt123\",\"phone_number\":\"55578912\"}}}"`

I tried to accomplish that using this code:

```
NSString *strurl=@"http://sub.domain.com/api/v1/sections.json";
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[strurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


[dict setValue:phoneTxt.text forKey:@"phone_number"];
[dict setValue:emailTxt.text forKey:@"email"];
[dict setValue:departmentTxt.text forKey:@"department"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request=[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];


NSDictionary *sectionDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:dict, @"properties", nil];

NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:sectionDic, @"section",nil];

SBJsonWriter *jsonWriter = [[SBJsonWriter alloc] init];
NSString *params = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:dic];

NSLog(@"param----%@",params);
[request setPostValue:params forKey:@"properties"];


[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

But the response that I have is the following:

Parameters: `{"section"=>"{\"properties\":{\"department\":\"dpt123\",\"email\":\"example@email.com\",\"phone_number\":\"55578912\"}}"}`

It gives me this error because it has properties as a string:

`NoMethodError (undefined method 'stringify_keys' for #<String:0x000000025dbc98>)`

How can I can POST using section and properties as keys. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the wrong method to create the dictionaries `sectionDic` and `dic`. `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` would expect arrays for both the objects and keys. instead try

```
NSDictionary *sectionDic = @{@"properties": dict};
NSDictionary *dic = @{@"section":sectionDic};
```